# JQMIGRATE: jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string

Tags: magento2, store-view, json

I am facing **JQMIGRATE: jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string** this error in console log on Aheadworks store locator, please if you know about this issue kindly tell me solution.

NOTE: JsonFactory is already defined in controller.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual error when the JSON string that you're trying to parse is empty.